# How to lock a table during an operation

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to lock a table when a store procedure is executing.

Would this be a good way?

```
CREATE PROCEDUE sp_test
@tableName nvarchar(128)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName + 'WITH TABLOCK'
EXEC @sql

-- DO my operations

-- How Do I release the lock? or does it get release when the execution is done
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need this, but I would expect severe lock contention if the proc is hit at all frequently.  Can you give details why you need it?

Comment: It shouldn't be hit frequently most probably once. We have a stored procedure that will enable change tracking for a specific table. When that procedure is call we wanna lock the table so that nobody can do DML operation on the table. Once the procedure is done, we wanna release the lock. The procedure won't take long to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take specific locks out on the table at the beginning of the procedure call.

If you wanted to prevent data modification to the table you could take an IX lock.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
    SELECT * FROM <<TABLENAME>> WITH(UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE 1=0;
    -- DO STUFF
    SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid;
COMMIT TRAN
```

If you wanted to prevent any other process from accessing the data you could take an X lock. Of course this doesn't prevent any uncommitted reads.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
    DELETE FROM <<TABLENAME>> WITH(XLOCK, TABLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE 1=0;
    -- DO STUFF 
    SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid;
COMMIT TRAN
```

The lock gets released when the transaction is either commited/rolled back.

Comment: for the X lock, why are you doing a delete? can't you do a select?